# Uploading files to a Heroku website connected to GitHub?

Tags: heroku, github, file-upload

I'm making a pretty simple website and I have a feature that allows users to upload an image for their profile which is then saved in an uploads directory.

It seems to work fine, however when I push a new local version of the site out I lose all the uploaded files. I'm not exactly sure where Heroku stores them, is there a way I can push those to GitHub or another solution?

Comment: How you are uploading to heroku?

Comment: I basically followed the technique here: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

I then save the file name/location in the database

Comment: Just go through heroku website. you will get all the details you want.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want data from heroku app to your repository, if i understood your question correctly. Then try this:

https://blog.heroku.com/push_and_pull_databases_to_and_from_heroku

Answer (score 0):

Heroku's filesystem is ephemeral. If you want to store user uploaded content, you need to use something like S3 to store the files.